# Incrementing badge value without a background task

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, uwp

I'm building a messaging app as a Universal Windows 8.1 Store Project and I'm a bit puzzled with the push notification system. I'm using WNS and the basic routine works fine (notification channel uri exchange, delivering toast notifications, etc.)

Now I want to increment badge value with server notifications and decrement it with local notifications. After digging the manuals I don't seem to find a way to do that without a background task that would receive raw notifications and do something to set the correct value. All I find available is [**setting** the value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br212849.aspx). I would rather avoid using background tasks at all as they can be blocked by battery saver (by user intention or not). Skype, for instance, doesn't seem to be capable of providing any notifications at all with background execution blocked, and I don't want my app to behave that way.

So, there are two questions I'd like answered:

1. Is there a way to increment/decrement badge value through notifications alone?
2. Is there a way to get current badge value in application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tile details, including the badge value, are read only.

Try not to think of the badge number as being incremented or decremented but rather just set to a new value.

You'll need to have code running to change the value. This could be in the local app (when it's running), in a background agent/task on the device or on a remote server somewhere.

To set a new value you'll have to know what that value should be. If it's relative to a previously displayed value you'll need to keep track of that separately.

So, in answer to your questions, in reverse order.

2) No, you can't read the value currently displayed.

1) You can increment or decrement the displayed value by setting it to a new, higher or lower, value. Setting the new value can only be done with an absolute value as there's no concept of an increment (or decrement) message. The notification sent to update the tile can be sent from anywhere (foreground, background or remote) but when and how this should be done will be dependent upon what is best for the app/user.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Unfortunatelly this confirms my findings. Since I want my app to be able to notify user of updates at all times (that's an instant messenger after all), I'm now resolved to implement remote-only updates of badge counter. This will require informing server of what updates were consumed by client, so it can figure out the correct remaining updates number. My teammates from iOS and Android do not seem to have equally hard times with this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried to do the same as you want to do but couldn't find anything and the best way is to do it with the help of background task and add the background task to always allow by overriding the controls when the user opens the app for the first time.

Hope, This helps you.